# MapKit, run method on location-service-permission being granted

Tags: iphone, permissions, location, mapkit

I have an app with a mapkit that loads annotations during the ViewDidLoad using a loadAnnotations method. But I don't want to run said method (load the annotations) until permission is granted to use the current userLocation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You request permission to use the users location using an instance of `CLLocationManager` (using `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`). You need to set the delegate of your [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and have it adhere to the [CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate). Specifically, you want to use this method on your delegate:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```